# python dictionary mydt problems

Tags: python

Write a Python program that will take N names from the user. Create a dictionary from the N names that will hold First_name, Middle_name, and Last_name in separate keys. The inputs will take N at first and then take N names. You can assume that the names will contain less than or equal to 3 words.

**Sample Input:**

```
4

Zubayer Ahmed

Sadia Nur Amin

Mehedi Hasan Shawon

Nafis
```

**Sample Output:**

```
 { "Fname" : [“Zubayer”, “Sadia”, “Mehedi”, “Nafis”] , "Mname" : [“Nur”, “Hasan”], "Lname" : [“Ahmed”, “Amin”, “Shawon”] }
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem requires you to first find the number of names needed, this can be done using a simple input() call.
`numNames = int(input("> "))`

we can also prepare the dictionary like so
`nameDict = {"Fname":[],"Mname":[],"Lname":[]}`

Then we need to iterate depending on the number the user has entered
`for i in range(numNames):`

During each iteration of the above for loop, you need to ask the user for a name, then split it into a list of each names `names = input("name {i+1} > ").split(" ")`

You can then add them to the dictionary as the problem requires using basic selection

```
if len(names) >= 1:
    nameDict["Fname"].append(names[0])

    if len(names) == 2:
        nameDict["Lname"].append(names[1])
    elif len(names) == 3:
        nameDict["Mname"].append(names[1])
        nameDict["Lname"].append(names[2])
```

This solution could be made more efficient if you can find a better way to sort the names into the dictionary.

Although StackOverflow isn't for your entire problems, more so questions about specific areas. Next time have a go at the problem and post if you get suck with details about your attempt.

But anyway, here is my full solution

```
numNames = int(input('names >'))

nameDict = {'Fname':[],'Mname':[],'Lname':[]}

for i in range(numNames):
    names = input(f'name {i+1} > ').split(' ')
    
    if len(names) >= 1:
        nameDict["Fname"].append(names[0])

        if len(names) == 2:
            nameDict["Lname"].append(names[1])
        elif len(names) == 3:
            nameDict["Mname"].append(names[1])
            nameDict["Lname"].append(names[2])

print(nameDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```py
number_of_entries = int(input("How many entries would you like? "))

first_names = []
middle_names = []
last_names = []

i = 0
while i < number_of_entries:
    full_name = input(": ")
    names_array = full_name.split(' ')
    
    if len(names_array) >= 1:
        first_names.append(names_array[0])
    if len(names_array) >= 2:
        middle_names.append(names_array[1])
    if len(names_array) >= 3:
        last_names.append(names_array[2])


    i += 1

names_dictionary = { "Fname" : first_names, "Mname" : middle_names, "Lname" : last_names}
print(names_dictionary)
```

It works by storing every category of name into an array first then adding that to the dictionary in the end.

Comment: thanks . its works ..

Answer (score 1):

In this homework, you must handle the initial 4 and read correctly the following input lines.

After that you will have a list of names, I think the best approach is the following

```
from itertools import zip_longest
names = ["Zubayer Ahmed","Sadia Nur Amin","Mehedi Hasan Shawon","Nafis"]

# split into single words
names = [x.split() for x in names]

# do a zip of the triads and remove None values
filtered = [ list(filter(None,_)) for _ in zip_longest(*names)]

#do the dict:
dict(zip( ("Fname","Mname", "Lname"), filtered))
```

the output:

```
{'Fname': ['Zubayer', 'Sadia', 'Mehedi', 'Nafis'],
 'Mname': ['Ahmed', 'Nur', 'Hasan'],
 'Lname': ['Amin', 'Shawon']}
```